# How to get background RunningTasks for other apps in java?

Tags: java, android

I want get background `RunningTask` for other apps by `specified Package`.
Example:
If 'com.example.app' is running on background, than show toast 'App is Running'
else
Show toast 'App is not running'
Thanks in advance.

here is my code example

```
public boolean isRunningApp(String packageName) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(packageName)) { //Other app, which is running on background.
                        Toast.makeText(this, "App is running!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "App is not running!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: That information is not generally available on modern versions of Android, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: any other method?